# Working on a script to recursively search folders for strings within files- but running into a white space issue

Tags: parsing, search, grep, whitespace, sh

Was wondering what the options were to address folders with white space, since unix doesn't like it. I checked around for solutions and people pointed to print0, but it seems to be exclusive to the find command? Is there something like that for grep?

```
FOLDER=$1
STRING=$2

grep -lr $STRING $FOLDER | while read file; do
  echo "Found String at " $file
  echo "Lines-"
  grep -n $STRING $file
  echo
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Your script should work OK as long as there are no filenames with newlines if you fix the second grep by adding double quotes:

```
grep -n "$STRING" "$file"
```